# Issue with stored procedure execution SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle apex that execute 4 other procedures that work by themselves alone, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong. And I don't really know what to change, could someone please help me?

```
create or replace procedure "UPDATE_COST"
is
begin
UPDATE orders
    SET order_price = (
        SELECT sum(total) 
        FROM detail_order 
        where detail_order.nord=orders.nord
        group by nord
    );
end;

create or replace procedure "Detail_quantity_proc"
is
begin
update detail_order d set
  d.total = (select d.quantity * p.price_exclvat
             from product p
             where p.npro = d.npro
            )
where exists (select null from product a
              where a.npro = d.npro
             );
end;

create or replace procedure "Proc_excl_vat"
is
begin
UPDATE bill
    SET PRICE_EXCL_VAT = (
        SELECT ORDER_PRICE 
        FROM orders 
        where orders.nord=bill.nord
    );
end;

create or replace procedure "Proc_INCL"
is
begin
UPDATE BILL SET PRICE_INCL_VAT = PRICE_EXCL_VAT*1.06;
end;

create or replace procedure "Fill_all_cost"
is
begin
execute UPDATE_COST;
execute Detail_quantity_proc;
execute Proc_excl_vat;
execute Proc_INCL;
end;
```

Comment: Those are **stored** procedures - procedures that are **stored** inside your Oracle database - they're not "stocked" :..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `execute` keyword. Also, you have those defined with double quotes, so they are case sensitive. Redefine them without the quotes:

```
create or replace procedure fill_all_costs
is
begin
    update_cost;
    detail_quantity_proc;
    proc_excl_vat;
    proc_incl;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this does not seem to resolve my issue. Oracle gives me an execution in progress error.

Comment: After I run the code Oracle says that my code is in progress even though it states that it was run in 0,05 seconds. It also states that there is one error.

Comment: What do you mean it says it's "in progress"? Are you running this in a job? And what is the error.

Comment: @groplo Are you running all the commands at once in a SQL worksheet? Depending on the client you're using, you may need to separate the code blocks with `/`.